# replace unwated characters in api response

Tags: python, json, api, request

I am using python to grab some data from an [API](https://search.censys.io/api) which turns into an enormous file quite fast. The problem that I am running into is there are unwanted characters on each `page` that is making my json file invalid format.

I think this is a Censys thing on large calls it requires a `page` and the only thing I can think of it to append the json response to file but it is incorporates this unwanted `}][{` at the end. If I do a find and replace in the json file with a text editor for find `}][{` replace with `},{` its good valid json.

Would anyone have a tip on how I can incorporate that into my script?

```
import json
from censys.search import CensysHosts
import time

h = CensysHosts()

data = h.search("services.#@.$:*", per_page=100, pages=500)

with open('data.json', 'a') as json_file:
    for page in data:
        json.dump(page, json_file)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Is this a better way of trying this below (untested)? I can only make so many API calls and not just be debugging on the fly...so any tips/better practices appreciated.

```
import json
from censys.search import CensysHosts
import time

h = CensysHosts()

data = h.search("services.#@.$:*", per_page=100, pages=500)

with open('data.json', 'a') as json_file:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i != len(data):

            data = data.replace('}][{', '},{')

        else:
            pass  # keep closing bracket for last page in resp

        json.dump(data[i], json_file)
```

Comment: What about saving one JSON file per result page, eg. something like `f"data_{page}.json"` and after you are done with it, postprocess the JSONs and concat them, to one big JSON file.

Comment: ah ok if you posted an answer ill hit the green check. That would work I use Pandas after that anyways to analyze the data. Thanks

Comment: It is very hard to assume what the loop would be like. The code you are having looks as if it queries `CensysHosts` once and returns a JSON response. Then it seems as you are saving the `data.json` once, too. Well as long as you got a solution to your issue, mission accomplished!